# Server controls in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to use server controls in ASP.MVC View. I want to retrive data from View and pass it to the control. How could I use server side controls(grid, button etc) and their events?

Answer (score 1):

You can use server controls on aspx views just like you would in ordinary aspx pages (for example, ListView is quite useful). 
You have to bind it to viewdata in the Page_Load function. 
Though, you cannot use any events related to postback (edit and paging in GridView, etc.).

Comment: So you need to send the correct URL as a request for the controller to reorder model data and re-create the view, as opposed to the extant Page model doing both?