# Alternatives to server controls in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, servercontrols

What is the replacement for a server control in ASP.NET MVC? What I want to do is to create a declarative and imperative binding so I can write

```
<cc1:MyControl Header="Some Header" Content="Some Content" />
```

which would mean that an instance of the MyControl class will be created and possibly rendered to

```
<h1>Some Header</h1>
<p>Content</p>
```

I don't want any viewstate or postback crap, just the modularity. I also want these modules to be contained in a separate class library, so ViewUserControls will not do for me. Using a server controls in the normal way works, but it generates a form tag and a viewstate field, which I do not want if I can avoid it.

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317995/server-controls-and-mvc) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264664/server-controls-in-asp-net-mvc) about how to use server controls in ASP.NET MVC, but they do not provide enough answer.

**Edit:** I found the answer. When I added the user control using the designer, it automatically created a <form> which I missed. If I simply remove that tag, everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use **all controls** in ASP.NET MVC if they don't require rendering in a server form.

`ascx` files and `@Register` directives still work pretty well. The great new thing is `Html.RenderPartial` method that lets you pass a model object to a partial view (`ascx`) and have it render accordingly.

Comment: As the question says, my problem is that whenever I create a server control, the form gets rendered, which I do not want.

Comment: This is not true for all controls. That's the issue with the specific control, not ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: The control I tested with is a blank control (I created a Server Control project and I'm testing with the default ServerControl1). How do I have to modify it to remove the view state?

Comment: I tested it and it doesn't generate any form tags or anything else whatsoever at runtime. There is, however, an issue with VS design view which creates a <form> tag when you drag a control to designer surface. You can easily remove the form tag in HTML mode.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding one more possibility to **Mehrdad** answer, you can use **extension methods** to do a simple control like this:

```
<%= html.MyControl( "Some header", "Some content" ) %>


<Extension()> _
Public Function MyControl(ByVal htmlHelper As HtmlHelper, _
                         ByVal Header As String, _
                         ByVal Content As String) As String

Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
sb.AppendFormat("<h1>{0}</h1>", Header)
sb.AppendFormat("<p>{0}</p>", Content)
Return sb.ToString()
End Function
```

Or you can make a more complex control like this example: [Create an ASP.NET MVC GridView Helper Method](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/06/25/asp-net-mvc-tip-8-create-an-asp-net-mvc-gridview-helper-method.aspx)

Comment: Sorry, it's too simple. I want my users to be able to use the VS2008 designer.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the controls which still work with ASP.Net MVC, you can use `mvc` controls.

- [Repeater example](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2009/04/07/ASPNETMVCControlsASPNETMVCFuturesRepeaterControlExample.aspx) - ***dead link***
- [Exploring ASP.Net MVC Futures](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/04/02/Back-to-the-future!-Exploring-ASPNET-MVC-Futures.aspx) - ***dead link***

**UPDATE**: This answer was for ASP.Net MVC 1.0 in 2009. It is outdated and irrelevant at this point.

Comment: Heads up: Both of your links are broken.